# Placing a HTML control over top of a Silverlight Application and have it scroll with the application

Tags: c#, html, css, silverlight, layout

I have a Silverlight Application (VS2010/C#) that is full screen.
   I also have a html control that is positioned overtop of the Silverlight Application.

When the browser window is maximized the position is correct.  However when I restore down the window to a smaller dimension I get scrollbars for the silverlight application (as expected).  When I scroll down my html does not scroll and remains floating relative to its window position.  I want the html to scroll with the silverlight application.  How can this be done?

I can not put the html in the silverlight application for business flow reasons.

Here are my **style sheets**

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body
    {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    body
    {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #silverlightControlHost
    {
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    }
    #contentDiv
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        right: 30px;
        display: inline;
        z-index: 20000;
    }
</style>
```

here is my **html code**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
    <div runat="server" id="contentDiv">
        --HTML CONTROLS
    </div>
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object id="silverlightControl" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
              <param name="windowless" value="true"/>
              <param name="enablehtmlaccess" value="true" />
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/GETSILVERLIGHT" style="text-decoration:none">
           <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object>
        <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thank you in advance for any help offered in this.

I feel like the scroll bar that is appearing belongs to the silverlight application and that is why when scrolling the html content seems to float, but I have been unable to confirm this theory.

**~~~EDIT~~~**

It has been confirmed that the scroll bars belong to the Silverlight instance.  To confirm this I set my html controls position to be to the far right and bottom by setting a large "LEFT" and "TOP" property in the CSS.
   At this point both the browser and the Silverlight App got scroll bars upon a resize.  The scroll bars for the browser and the silverlight app were different styles.
   After reseting the LEFT and TOP attributes and reproducing the original issue the scrollbars that were appearing had the same style as the Silverlight App and not the window.  So all scrolling is happening on the Silverlight App itself.

   Moving forward a solution may be to break the business flow and imbed the html within the Silverlight.  If someone can think of a different way to accomplish this it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By capturing the scroll event I was able to adjust the top attribute of my control and allow a scrolling like effect.  Here is the basis of the solution.

Note: svMainViewer is the scroll View in the MainShell.xaml page

**C# MainShell.xaml.cs code**

```
public partial class MainShell : UserControl
{
    #region Private Variables
    private double svHorizontalOffset;
    private double svVerticalOffset;
    #endregion

    #region Constants
    const string JAVASCRIPT_FUNCTION_VERTICALOFFSETCHANGED = "SilverlightScrollViewerVerticalOffest";
    const string JAVASCRIPT_FUNCTION_HORIZONTALOFFSETCHANGED = "SilverlightScrollViewerHorizontalOffest";
    #endregion
    public MainShell(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        #region Code required registering scroll bar offset notifications
        NotificationHelper.RegisterForNotification("HorizontalOffset", svMainShell, OnHorizontalOffsetChanged);
        NotificationHelper.RegisterForNotification("VerticalOffset", svMainShell, OnVerticalOffsetChanged);
        #endregion
    }

    #region Methods using dependency properties
    public void OnHorizontalOffsetChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        svHorizontalOffset = double.Parse(e.NewValue.ToString());
        System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Invoke(JAVASCRIPT_FUNCTION_HORIZONTALOFFSETCHANGED, svHorizontalOffset);
    }

    public void OnVerticalOffsetChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        svVerticalOffset = double.Parse(e.NewValue.ToString());
        System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Invoke(JAVASCRIPT_FUNCTION_VERTICALOFFSETCHANGED, svVerticalOffset);
    }
    #endregion

}

public class NotificationHelper
{
    public static void RegisterForNotification(string property, FrameworkElement frameworkElement, PropertyChangedCallback OnCallBack)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding(property)
        {
            Source = frameworkElement
        };

        var dependencyproperty = System.Windows.DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ListenAttached" + property,
                                 typeof(object), typeof(UserControl), new System.Windows.PropertyMetadata(OnCallBack));

        frameworkElement.SetBinding(dependencyproperty, binding);
    }
}
```

**Javascript Code Snippet**

```
function SilverlightScrollViewerVerticalOffest(offset) 
{
        contentDivElement = document.getElementById("contentDiv");
        if (contentDivElement != null && contentDivElement.style.display != 'none') 
        {
            contentDivElementTop = 15 - offset;
            contentDivElementTop += 'px';
            contentDivElement .style.top = contentDivElementTop ;
        }
}
```

You may find more detail on the code I implemented at Weareon's blog at  http://blog.weareon.net/scrollviewer-scroll-change-event-in-silverlight/